# Upload patch set preserving existing reviews

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

We use Jenkins to verify patch sets. Sometimes Jenkins needs do some changes on the patch set. So it `commit --amend` the changes and then uploads the new patch set.

It work nicely besides the fact, that all manual reviews made to the original patch set get erased.

- How can I push a new patch set (from Jenkins) without loosing all existing reviews/votes?

Comment: Plugin consideration question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482418/gerrit-plugin-to-preserve-reviews-scores-if-pushing-from-jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that, in the situation you have described, you have a new patchset and, excluding in special situations, you don't want votes of the old patchset copied forward to the new patchset. For example: if someone have approved the patchset1 and Jenkins pushes the patchset2, probably he/she doesn't want to have his/her vote automatically copied to patchset2.

Said that: you can control how votes will/won't be copied forward to new patchset setting the label.LABEL-NAME.copyXXXXX options of the project. See more info in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_copyMinScore).

Comment: The idea is, that only the Jenkins-push copies the reviews. Is it also possible to configure with something like `git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master%Label-Name.copyMaxScore=true` ?

Comment: No, there isn't such push option: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_options

Comment: Is it possible to add this push `%` option through a plugin API? I didn't found any examples of this in the cookbook plugin. Thank you!!

Comment: I don't know :-(

Comment: I related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482418/gerrit-plugin-to-preserve-reviews-scores-if-pushing-from-jenkins So the discussion may continue there.